# Msbuild not working (initializeComponents) in Jenkins but Working on Msbuild local

Tags: jenkins, xamarin.forms, msbuild

I'm trying to integrate CI with jenkins and `Xamarin.Forms`, but, when I build with Jenkins, the build failed with next error:

> App.xaml.cs(12,13): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context [closed]

If I build on my local machine with cmd command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" .\Notes\Notes.Android\Notes.Android.csproj /P:Configuration=Debug
```

It works perfectly.

Any have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You need to give us a LOT more information. Just saying it failed on Jenkins is not enough. We don't have access to that Jenkins server, and without knowing what you are calling in Jenkins, we are operating blind.

Comment: Most likely some issues with environment variables or path. Compare output of `set` on your machine and jenkins.

Comment: Having a check with namespace whether be consistent with solution's name in project.